# Spring Boot and Tomcat not finding JNDI resources

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I'm using `Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE`.  I'm also using `Tomcat 8.5.9` (NOT embedded) and `Java 8`.

In my `application.properties` file, I can manually configure my datasource using:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:as400://blahblah....
spring.datasource.username = myuser
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

This works just fine.  But, we use Tomcat to host our connections.  In Tomcat, we have:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/BLAH" ..... />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

So I then changed application.properties to:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/BLAH
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Now, I can't even build the application.  I get the following exception:

```
o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: 

Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: 

Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: 

Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/BLAH'; 

nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: 
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, 
or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

The `NoInitialContextException` leads me to believe that Spring Boot cannot find Tomcat running so it can't perform a JNDI lookup.

Keep in mind, the *exact* same setup worked for us using Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE.  We have another app that uses 1.2.5.RELEASE, Java 7 and Tomcat 7 and it works using JNDI resources.  But using the newest Spring Boot, Java 8 and Tomcat 8 doesn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Some snippets from my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
        <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
        <version>6.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

Other code snippets:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.myapp")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.myapp.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableVaadin
@EnableVaadinServlet
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've created the resources within Tomcat (external) using the `GlobalNamingResources` in our `server.xml`.
This works for other applications.

**UPDATE 2**

Forgot to mention that I have the following in a `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/BLAH"
                  name="jdbc/BLAH"
                  type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"/>
</Context>
```

**UPDATE 3**

Also, I want to make it clear the problem happens during the `maven package` step.

Comment: Have you tried referencing the resource with a preceding slash? (i.e. java:/...)  spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/BLAH

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're saying.

Comment: Nope.  Still the same.  I also tried `/jdbc/BLAH` and `jdbc/BLAH`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying on a standalone Tomcat (Not embedded), I'm fairly sure you need to define your JNDI resources on the Tomcat and not in application.properties, but in server.xml like this:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/serverdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="5" maxIdle="5" maxWaitMillis="30000"
              validationQuery="select 1" testOnBorrow="true"
              username="$AUTH_DB_USER" password="$AUTH_DB_PASSWORD" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://$AUTH_DB_HOST:5432/$AUTH_DB_NAME"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Comment: I've done that.  I wasn't very clear but that's how we normally do our apps.  I will update to reflect that I've done that.

Comment: I have two hints, the first is that you may need a ResourceLink in the context.xml, which references the global resource defined in server.xml.  The second step would be to set a breakpoint in JndiLocatorSupport.lookup (I'm guessing it is used in Boot) and then debug the JNDI tree.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I already have the context entry.  I will mark my question to reflect that.  I will try the breakpoint too.

Comment: I have not tried the JDNI with a Boot war file, but I got several Tomcat 8 apps that work fine with JNDI, but there I create JndiDataSourceLookup myself to get the DataSource. We don't prefix with "java:comp/env/" but that is because we explicit set JndiDataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true), so it will be prefixed -default is false so you may need to set it

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you're doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: It over a year ago, and it looked like that from the first commit, so either I read the documentation, or copied it from somewhere - We did't use boot, and even if we did we application.properties would probably be empty.